# What is this specific `where` clause, is it a closure or function of some sort, or an enum?

Tags: rust

I see two different things:

```
fn for_each<F>(self, f: F) where F: FnMut(Self::Item)
```

And:

```
fn cmp_by<I, F>(self, other: I, cmp: F) -> Ordering where I: IntoIterator, F: FnMut(Self::Item, <I as IntoIterator>::Item) -> Ordering
```

One has the `->` and the other doesn't. They are both called `Fn`, which makes me think it might be a closure. But I don't see any [examples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html).

What do the where clauses mean exactly in this situation?

Comment: The `-> SomeType` indicates that the function returns `SomeType`, there `where ...` clause is a separate bit of syntax specifying bounds on the generics.

Comment: If you're referring to the `->` *after* the `where` bounds, it's a special syntax for the `Fn` trait, `F: Fn(A) -> B` means `F` is a function (possibly a closure) that accepts `A` and returns `B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rust annotates a return type with `->`.

```rust
fn foo() -> i32 { ... }
```

When the function returns `()`, you can omit it for convenience. `fn foo() -> () {}` is the same as `fn foo() {}`.

The same thing happens with function pointers and closures: `fn() -> ()` (a pointer to function returning `()`) can be written as just `fn()`, and in the same manner, `Fn() -> ()` (should be part of a generic constraint or `dyn`, a function/closure implementing [the `Fn` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Fn.html)) can be written as just `Fn()`.

So,

```rust
fn for_each<F>(self, f: F) where F: FnMut(Self::Item)
```

Takes a function (or closure) that takes `Self::Item` and returns nothing. And

```rust
fn cmp_by<I, F>(self, other: I, cmp: F) -> Ordering where I: IntoIterator, F: FnMut(Self::Item, <I as IntoIterator>::Item) -> Ordering
```

Takes (besides the other iterator `other`) a function that takes `Self::Item` and `I::Item` and returns `Ordering` ([`std::cmp::Ordering`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html)).